# Разработать функцию, которая для заданного натурального числа N возвращает количество его делителей

Tags: python

Возникла проблема с заданием, не могу найти ошибку:
Разработать функцию, которая для заданного натурального числа N возвращает количество его делителей. С помощью данной функции: для заданного числа А вывести на экран следующее по отношению к нему число, имеющее столько же делителей, сколько и число А.

Например, если ввести число 4, то должно вывести 6, но не ничего не выводится

```
def function(n):
  i=1
  m=0
  while i<=n:
    if n%i == 0:
      m+=1
      i+=1
  print(m)
a=int(input())
b=a+1
while function(a)!= function(b):
  b=+1
else:
  print(b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для 4 следующее будет 9, т.к. у 6 четыре делителя, а нечётное количество - только у квадратов

Ошибки:
- i нужно было увеличивать в любом случае
- функция должна возвращать результат
- инкремент b+=1,а не b=+1

```
def function(n):
    i=1
    m=0
    while i<=n:
        if n%i == 0:
            m+=1
        i+=1
    return m
a=int(input())
b=a+1
while function(a)!= function(b):
    b+=1
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Оптимизированный вариант

```py
import math

def countDividers(n):
    if n <= 0: return 0 # условно будем так считать
    if n == 1: return 1

    k = 2 # делителей изначально 2, само число и единица.
    for i in range(2, round(math.sqrt(n)) + 1): # максимально можем оптимизировать поделив на 2 (пример: 60 % 30 == 0)
        if n % i == 0:
            k += 1 if i == n // i else 2
    return k


a = int(input())
b = a + 1
while countDividers(a) != countDividers(b):
    b += 1
print(b)
```